# How can I disable the new NPM spinner in the command-line?

Tags: unit-testing, command-line, npm, spinner

It is mucking up the display of my unit tests, is there a simple way to turn it off?

[image]

Comment: They should remove this console progress nonsense completly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ah found it! Run `npm config set spin=false` will disable it

Comment: What version of npm? This didn't work for npm v3.10.5

Answer (score 11):

I believe answer to the literal question of how to do it on the command line (rather than via changing the config file) is `npm --no-spin`.

Comment: I think this is called `progress` in npm3 so `npm config set progress=false` should do the trick. According to https://twitter.com/gavinjoyce/status/691783314261331969 it's also faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on the fly, like this:

```
npm install --no-progress
```

Confirmed works in v3.10.9

Answer (score 0):

With NPM 3, run this prior to `npm install`:

```
$ npm config set progress=false
```